# What is the Java equivalent of 'define' in PHP?

Tags: java, php

I'm trying to define something in my code, but there isn't any [`define`](http://www.php.net/define) in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
final String key = Value;
```

For example,

```
final String MAX_VALUE = "9000";
```

And it's better to add *static* too:

```
static final String MAX_VALUE = "9000";
```

Comment: That's not a valid example.

Comment: Even better if you make it `static` too.

Comment: I agree. Edited my answer.

Comment: How could I make multiple strings = 9000?

Comment: What do you mean by multiple strings = 9000 ?
You can make many constants as you want :
static final String MAX_VALUE = "9000";
static final String MAX_VALUE2 = "9000"; static final String MAX_VALUE3 = "9000";

Answer (score 1):

Java as such does not exactly "have" constants (which is what you define using the define() function in PHP). Rather, you can make the variable final. This way, it behaves like a constant value (i.e., can not be changed).

So something like:

```
final int NUMBER_OF_HOURS_IN_A_DAY = 24;
```

will create a "constant" integer with a value of 24.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517978/java-constant-variable-examples
Also has a good answer to this.

Comment: Even better if you make it static too.

Comment: That's true; but it really depends on the context. Could also make it public ;)